# Send Alert to Page after POST Data from Form Sent to Database - PHP, JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post, alert

I have a form.  When the form data are submitted, I'd like to send the user a JavaScript alert saying, 'thanks for submitting the form'.

I'm looking for some kind of conditional to use to make this possible.  I tried testing the $_POST array with `isset` and even though the `print_r` was showing an empty array, the alert came up.  Seemed unreliable.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Really?  -3.  That seems a bit harsh.

Comment: I thought it was the policy of these boards to actually post constructive reasons why a down-vote is made rather than hiding behind anonymous down-votes?  Weak ;-(

Comment: no code, no effort to solve it yourself shown, insulting comments -1 from me.

Comment: Thank you Dagon.  I'm not sure I was insulting anywhere.  And I didn't realize that code was required.  And, how do you know I put no effort into it?  I often come here after some effort to get good ideas and I do so because it works.  I appreciate you coming forward though and explaining yourself.  That's your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   echo <<<EOL
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('POST received');
</script>
EOL;
}
```

the REQUEST_METHOD is the only 100% reliable method of testing if a particular type of HTTP request is active. Checking form fields is unreliable - field names can get typoed, missed, deleted, hacked, etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'):?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   alert('POST received');
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

a different way of writing Marc B's answer

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to say Thanks for submitting form, why not just add `onclick` on the submit button.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="alert('Thank you for submitting the form!');" value="Submit Form">
```

For submitting it after the data reception, in PHP,

```
if (isset($_POST['whatever']) && (more_conditions) {
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successful Submission.)</script>";
}
```

Comment: Because I'm already using `onclick` for something.  Plus, when they click, this doesn't mean the form is submitted successfully...

Comment: You can add multiple functions in the `onclick`, So using it for something else isn't a hurdle. For adding other conditions, check the edit.

Comment: I tried variations of your answer as I indicated and the results were varied.  I will try some additional tests.

Comment: I ended up using your idea, Hrishikesh, and added the thanks alert to the `onsubmit` handler and now it works just the way I want it - thanks!